# Couldn't import class to Java project

Tags: java, dependencies, trie

I am trying to import

```
import org.apache.commons.collections4.trie.PatriciaTrie;
```

It gives me error that it does not exists. I am using Lucene with Glassfish server.

What should be done to fix that issue?

Comment: you need to add the package to your classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use any kind of central repository system (Maven, SBT, Ivy, Gradle) in your project you could add this dependency with help of this link

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4/4.0

E.g. for Maven it will be -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
    <version>4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

If you don't use it, you should add needed library to classpath manually.